# Slow binary pattern matching function

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I made a simple binary pattern matching function. However the GC goes crazy and my code takes a while to process a small 4Mb file (more than one minute). I made a test with python and it processes the same file in less than 5 seconds.
Here is the code:

```
public void searchPattern(byte[] pattern){
    try {
        // file is a RandomAccesFile
        file.seek(0);
        long i = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[pattern.length];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(i < file.length()-pattern.length){
            file.seek(i);
            file.read(buff);
            if(Arrays.equals(pattern,buff)){
                Log.d("BinaryFile","Match found --> " + Long.toHexString(i));
            }
            i += 1;
        }
        Log.d("BinaryFile","Analysis finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000 + "s");

    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

file is a randomaccessfile , any ideas ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the implementations same? algorithmically I mean

Comment: Yes the implementation are the same